# Pyparsing sum of optionally repeated expressions

Tags: python-2.7, sum, repeat, pyparsing

I am working on an simple parser to handle expression such as:

```
"""
FOO*1.5
+
BAR*3
"""
```

To get an end numeric result, where `FOO` and `BAR` are replaced at runtime by the values returned by external function executions. For example: `FOO ---> def foo():return 2` and `BAR ---> def bar():return 4`. Which in our example would yield `(2*1.5)+(4*3) = 3+12 = 14`.

This is what I have so far:

```
from pyparsing import *
from decimal import Decimal

WEIGHT_OPERATORS = ['*', '/']
NUMERIC_OPERATORS = ['+', '-']

def make_score(input):
    if input[0] == 'FOO':
         return 5
    elif input[0] == 'BAR':
         return 10
    return 1

def make_decimal(input):
    try:
        return Decimal(input[0])
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return 0

SCORE = Word(alphanums + '_').setParseAction(make_score)
WEIGHT_OPERATOR = oneOf(WEIGHT_OPERATORS)
WEIGHT = Word(nums+'.').setParseAction(make_decimal)
INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION = SCORE('score') \
                        + WEIGHT_OPERATOR('weight_operator') \
                        + WEIGHT('weight')

print INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION
print INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION.parseString(expression).dump()
```

Up to here, all works well.

What I miss is the ability to "chain" INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSIONs together to add/substract them together, as in the simple example above. I have tried:

```
GLOBAL_EXPRESSION = infixNotation(
    INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION,
    [
        (NUMERIC_OPERATORS, 2, opAssoc.RIGHT,)
        # or (NUMERIC_OPERATORS, 1, opAssoc.LEFT,), etc... :(
    ]
)
print GLOBAL_EXPRESSION
print GLOBAL_EXPRESSION.parseString(expression).dump()
```

Nope.

And:

```
INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION = SCORE('score') \
                        + WEIGHT_OPERATOR('weight_operator') \
                        + WEIGHT('weight')
                        + ZeroOrMore(NUMERIC_OPERATORS)
```

To get the final list or dict that would easy to compute, to no avail. I am doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Pyparsing 3.0 will be coming out shortly, and will only support Python 3.5 and above. You will still be able to use Pyparsing 2.4.2 with Py2.7, but further maintenance of the Py2.x-compatible code will be limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GLOBAL_EXPRESSION = OneOrMore(Group(INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION) + Optional(oneOf(NUMERIC_OPERATORS)))

GE_LIST = Group(delimitedList(GLOBAL_EXPRESSION))

print GE_LIST.parseString(expression)
```

Comment: `delimitedList` is best used with a list where the delimiters will be discarded after parsing. In this case, the only delimiters might be the multiplication/division operators, but they are important to keep around for the evaluation phase, so the can't be discarded. The use of `Group` is important to keep the results names in the various individual terms from colliding with each other. I would suggest a better GLOBAL_EXPRESSION might be (assuming INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION was defined using a Group): `GLOBAL_EXPRESSION = INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION + ZeroOrMore(NUMERIC_OPERATOR + INDIVIDUAL_EXPRESSION)`